# Laravel eloquent leftJoin ignores orderByDesc when used

Tags: php, laravel

Well, I have tried a couple of days trying to find out what is wrong with my code.
I have a `chat_group` and `chat_message` tables respectively where each `group` has `last_message` that `belongs to` each `message` sent to a `group`.
When I want fetch all the groups based on the last message sent to a group `create_at` field, `laravel join` ignores the `orderBy`.
Here is a piece of my code and DB structure of it:

```
chat_groups: 
id, 
name, 
last_message_id, 
created_at

chat_messages: 
id: 
text: 
created_at
```

```
$groups = ChatGroup::with($relations) 
    ->leftJoin('chat_messages', 'chat_groups.last_message_id', '=', 'chat_messages.id')
    ->withCount('members') 
    ->orderBy('chat_messages.created_at', 'DESC') 
    ->orderBy('chat_groups.created_at', 'DESC') 
    ->get(); 
dd($groups->toArray());
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the most recent of the two tables? As it is right now, it will sort by chat_messages.created_at, then chat_groups.created_at. Unless two timestamps on the first table are the same, the orderBy will never really come into play.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want sort the records initially by created_at field of chat_group and then by the last message created_at of the group to get the groups that has the latest message sent to the group and comes first when querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.
I used order by clause on group updated_at field and no need to use leftJoin.